# If path doesn't exist try another path

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to get the following to work can someone please assist me using bash.

If the following path "/opt/james/Mike${INSTANCE}/local/log/appserver.log" doesn't exist try this instead: "/opt/james/Mike${INSTANCE}/log/appserver.log"

What I have tried so far:

```
printf "waiting for the app to start..."
{ tail -n 0 -f /opt/james/Mike${INSTANCE}/local/log/appserver.log & } | sed -n '/Server startup in/q'

{
if [ ! -f "/opt/james/Mike${INSTANCE}/local/log/appserver.log" ]; then
    echo "/opt/james/Mike${INSTANCE}/log/appserver.log"
    exit 0
fi
```

Is there a better way to write this?

Comment: The `&` is probably completely wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like this?

```
for p in "/opt/james/Mike${INSTANCE}/local/log" "/opt/james/Mike${INSTANCE}/log"; do
    test -f "$p/appserver.log" || continue
    log=$p/appserver.log
done
: maybe fail if "$log" is unset
: do things with "$log"
```

Comment: hmm so this will check if any of these paths exists to tail them right? What do you mean by "test -f"?

Comment: You used it in your own script, though it helps of course to know that `test` and `[` are synonyms. `test -f` checks if the argument is an existing regular file. This is very easy to find in the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html), or at the prompt: `help test`